# Why does latex throw an error when there is empty lines inside the caption environment

Tags: floats, errors, captions, compilation-error

Here is an effect i've irritated me on for a while.

When creating a figure environment with a caption like the one below

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
%%%Some figure
\caption{Some text
some more text

some text after a double line break}
\end{figure}
```

latex throws an error if I leave any line empty.

> pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file my_file.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group included in a single page >]
>   Runaway argument?
>   {Some text some more text 
>   ! Paragraph ended before \caption@prepareanchor was complete.
>    
>                      \par 
>   l.xxx some text after a double line break}

My simple and maybe naive question is, why is this? Can one get around it except by adding a comment '%' in the gap of the empty line?

Comment: The error message and the resolution is listed in the `caption` package documentation, section A.4 "Errors".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error from

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
%%%Some figure
\caption{Some text
some more text

some text after a double line break}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

is

```
! Paragraph ended before \addcontentsline was complete.
```

because the standard table of contents code is not set up for multi-paragraph captions, so you can supply a short version for the toc:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
%%%Some figure
\caption[zz]{Some text
some more text

some text after a double line break}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe i'm blind by i dont see the difference between the two code snippets...

Comment: @MikaelFremling oops I put the corrected version in twice, I'll delete `[zz]` from the  first one, thanks!!!!

Comment: Hi @MikaelFremling I am getting the same error and unfortunetely couldn't get the resolution, although this answer is accepted. I like putting some lines among different parts in latex but do not like getting these runaway argument errors. Can you please help?

Comment: @Ferda-Ozdemir-Sonmez "I like putting some lines among different parts in latex " sorry that is saying "I like adding syntax errors  but do not like the error messages" White space in TeX plays a specific syntactic role and can't just be added in random places.

Comment: @Ferda-Ozdemir-Sonmez the easy solution is to put "%%" on every empty line. This is since latex simply ignores the lines then.

Comment: Thanks @MikaelFremling :)